# How do I remove the extra carriage return when pasting HTML content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a customized email signature for the users of my website. I have a signature written in HTML that gets selected via a button. The button runs a JS and Jquery function to select the signature wrapper. When the html is copied and pasted it adds an unwanted extra line at the end.

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="signature-wrapper" id="signature">
  <img id="image" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/8b/f5/00/8bf500fb1a32d726c98e23b8c3e3ecf9.jpg" alt="Logo">
    <table id="signature-table">
      <tbody>
        <tr id="signature-line-1">
          <td>Name | Position</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="signature-line-2">
          <td>E: example@example.com | P: 000.000.0000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="blank">
        </tr>
        <tr id="signature-line-3">
          <td>Facebook | Twitter | Indeed</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button id="select-button" onclick="selectSignature('#signature')">Select Signature</button>
</body>
```

JS

```
selectSignature = function(elementId) {
  $(elementId).selectText();
};

jQuery.fn.selectText = function() {
  var range, selection;
  if (window.getSelection) {
    selection = window.getSelection();
    range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(this[0]);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
};
```

CSS

```
.signature-wrapper {
  height: 80px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
#signature-table {
  padding-top: 3px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#signature-line-1 {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 10px;
}
#image {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#signature-line-2, #signature-line-3 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  line-height: 20px;
}
#blank {
  height: 10px;
}
```

I have a JSFiddle with a simplified version of my signature generator to duplicate the problem [here](https://jsfiddle.net/728udebg/).

Probably the easiest way to duplicate the problem is to open my fiddle, copy the text and paste it into a new email like you would a signature.

The extra line is pushing the text higher than the image next to it and causing alignment issues. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I think this line is from the interpreted HTML (after `<img id="image" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/8b/f5/00/8bf500fb1a32d726c98e23b8c3e3ecf9.jpg" alt="Logo">`). Hum, by my knowledge this happens

Answer (score 1):

ok. for some reason, it works when you use code with no spaces. There is that one little thing somewhere.

https://jsfiddle.net/728udebg/1/

```
<div class="signature-wrapper" id="signature"><table id="signature-table"><tbody><tr id="signature-line-1"><td rowspan="2"><img id="image" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/8b/f5/00/8bf500fb1a32d726c98e23b8c3e3ecf9.jpg" alt="Logo"></td><td>Name | Position</td></tr><tr id="signature-line-2"><td>E: example@example.com | P: 000.000.0000</td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

Comment: Thats interesting... It puts the new line after the table in that example. My current solution is to have a table with one row and two cells, the first being the picture with vertical-align: top, the second being the text signature. This way it pushes the picture up as well as the text.